# Distributing an iOS framework with Swift package management dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, grpc, ios-frameworks, swift-package-manager

We are developing an iOS framework called FramworkSDK and would like to distribute it to our clients as a binary. The FrameworkSDK depends on a framework called swift-GRPC. We use the Swift package manager to add this dependency.

Currently, when I add the binary version of FrameworkSDK to my test app it throws errors like "unable to find module x".  The modules that the errors are referencing are modules included in the swift-GRPC package.

I assume, when I build the FrameworkSDK all of the dependencies are included in the bundle, Is this correct? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot depend on a Swift Package in a framework. This is discussed in the WWDC 2019 Talk [Binary Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/?time=2236). I have linked to the discussion of dependencies/entitlements and shortly after the time linked here it is specifically stated:

> binary frameworks cannot depend on on Packages.

So if you need to depend no the package you will likely need to set it up differently on how you depend on it. It will need to be a sibling dependency that is given to you also as a framework through a different package manager or you will need build the code in your module as if you owned it. Building it into your module can be nasty and more work for you but it is the most transparent for users if it is an implementation detail they don't care about.